# how can i check equal if one array before sorted and after sorted

Tags: java, arrays

it sounds crazy I know. I'm newbie at programming and having trouble with somethings. 
Lately, I've been doing some arrays and I know how to check equals two other arrays like using Arrays.equals(object, object)   but what I mean is I am working on 1 array. I want to check equals if the array is after sorted and before sorted.

```
System.out.println("your array before sorted: " + Arrays.toString(size));
//System.out.println("total of the elements: " +sum);
Arrays.sort(size);
System.out.println("your array after sorted: "+ Arrays.toString(size)); 
if(Arrays.equals(size, size)) {
    System.out.println("true af ");
}
```

I tried to create a variable which stores the sorted array but it gives my an error `cannot convert from void to int or something" because Arrays.sort(object) function returns void`. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Paste the code as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: You can copy the array into another array and check that.

Comment: You are doing a comparaison like `size == size` . It is the same as `1 == 1`, it is always true. You need to duplicate the array before the sort operation, then compare both array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to copy contents of array into another array in order to compare otherwise you end up refering to same array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] sizebefore = { 3, 5, 1, 8 };
        int[] sizeafter = new int[sizebefore.length];
        System.arraycopy(sizebefore, 0, sizeafter, 0, sizebefore.length);

        Arrays.sort(sizeafter);
        System.out.println("your array before sorted: " + Arrays.toString(sizebefore));
        System.out.println("your array after sorted: " + Arrays.toString(sizeafter));

        if (Arrays.equals(sizebefore, sizeafter)) {
            System.out.println("Matches after sort ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Doesn't match after sort ");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: i didnt want to create 2 arrays but it looks right okay thx a lot